# why can't I use 'query' ? Autocomplete backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, autocomplete

I'm trying to get a autocomplete search to work on my small app but for some reason I can't use the word 'query'.

When I use this code,

```
$.param({movieName: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val() 
  }); 
},
```

I get the url http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942xx8a28d7cadad4&movieName=movie which gives a 404

For the url to work I have to replace the word movieName with query, but when I do that I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

Can anyone explain me why I can't use the word query?

//edit. I forgot to past a part of my code,

```
.resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
  return resp.results.moviematches.movieName;
};
```

// edit. Let me just paste my whole code

```
%form#autocomplete-remote
  %input{:autocomplete => "off", :name => "search", :style => "width: 200px", :id => "movieName"}/

:javascript

  autocompleteRemote = new Backbone.AutocompleteList({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api + '&'  +
      $.param({query: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val()})
    },

  filter: null,

  el: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]'),
  template: _.template(
    '<p><%= name.replace(new RegExp("(" + $("form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]").val() + ")", "i") ,"<b>$1</b>") %></p>'
),
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 3,
  value: function(model) { return model.get('name') }
  ,

  }) 

  .resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
    return resp.results.moviematches.query;
  };

var api = 'a8f7039633f2065942xx8a28d7cadad4'
```

After messing around I've at least found out that the problem isn't with the word. Because I'm using thise code now

```
:javascript

autocompleteRemote = new Backbone.AutocompleteList({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api + '&q' + $.param({uery: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val()})
  },

  filter: null,

  el: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]'),
  template: _.template(
    '<p><%= name.replace(new RegExp("(" + $("form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]").val() + ")", "i") ,"<b>$1</b>") %></p>'
  ),
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 3,
  value: function(model) { return model.get('name') }
  ,

  })

  .resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
    return resp.results.moviematches.uery;
  };

  var api = 'a8f7039633f2065942xx8a28d7cadad4'
```

And I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uery' of undefined` even though this creates the desired URL.

Comment: One or more of your variables are undefined, doesn't necessarily have to do with the actual word 'query'. Are you sure 'query' is defined?

Comment: Like I said, I only get that error when I use the word 'query', I can use any word and at least my JS works. When I use 'query' it gives that error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a pair name/value

```
$.param({name: "movieName", value: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val() 
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: When I do this I just add stuff to the url `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942xx8a28d7cadad4&name=query&value=inception` so I'm afraid this isn't it either. I'm thinking about storing the input from the searchfield in a variable and then insert it into the url.